# Python minidom parser: Ignore tag with identical attribute values

Tags: python, list, attributes, minidom

Trying to parse xml to text I got something like this,

INPUT FILE

```
<Item id="1"></Item>
<Item id="2"></Item>
<Item id="1"></Item>
<Item id="2"></Item>
```

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
 Item ->1
 Item ->2
 Item ->2
 Item ->1
```

My DESIRED OUTPUT would be,

```
Item ->1
Item ->2
```

(Ignoring repeated id values)

The current code I'm using to obtain my CURRENT OUTPUT is,

```
list = node.getElementsByTagName('Item')
for item in list:
  output_id = item.getAttribute('id')
  print "Item ->", output_id
```

I've tried thousands of list remove methods but they all output the double ids. Help would be greatly appreciated.
Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, every DOM parser will return doubled ids as they're different elements.
To avoid, go through dom tree and store results in `dict` object. This will get you only last items.

**UPD:**

```
list = node.getElementsByTagName('Item')
items = {}
for item in list:
  output_id = item.getAttribute('id')
  items[output_id] = item # Put items into dict to use them later.
for id in items:
  print "Item[%d] -> %s" % (id, items[id]) # Only single item per id left.
```

And more 'pythonic' way:

```
list = node.getElementsByTagName('Item')
items = dict((item.getAttribute('id'), item) for item in list)
for id in items:
  print "Item[%d] -> %s" % (id, items[id]) # Only single item per id left.
```

Comment: Just learning Python. My background is C and did not work with objects except in the form of struct. Can you send a link to code I can apply based on what I have? Tks.

Comment: Thanks both, first example worked by changing the integer descriptor to string, while the second example prints the last id only. Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary instead. The output_id as the key.

If you want to have only the last element with each id:

```
list = node.getElementsByTagName('Item')
item_dict = {}
for item in list:
  output_id = item.getAttribute('id')
  item_dict [output_id] = item
```

Comment: Just learning Python. My background is C and did not work with objects except in the form of struct. Can you send a link to code I can apply based on what I have? Tks.

Comment: Thanks for the approach, however it kept throwing me the duplicates. Sample #1 from Dair T'arg was the only one able to output what I needed. Appreciate your help.